# Capture Out going Call in My app

Tags: iphone

Would any one help me.

I have developed one application and application is baked stage and now i am making a call.

Once i make a call to any one my application should should be activated autometically.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that's simply not possible with an unjailbroken iPhone.

Comment: Any way to come out from my issue.I need to active my application once i give a call to any one.